# Are there any viable ways of error handling multiple tkinter entries at once without a huge try except block?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm wondering if there are more elegant ways of handling multiple tk entries simultaneously which don't use a single nested try except block. In this example, whether there are ways of error handling these entries without lengthy and/or many if statements. As my program handles many entries at once, this is a fairly pressing matter.

I can't really think of other ways of achieving this.

```
import tkinter as tk

    class Main(tk.Tk):

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

            container = tk.Frame(self)
            container.grid(row=0, column=0)

            self.frames = {}

            for F in (Page1, Page2):
                frame = F(container, self)
                self.frames[F] = frame
                frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

            self.show_frame(Page1)

        def show_frame(self, page_name):
            frame = self.frames[page_name]
            frame.tkraise()

        def get_page(self, page_name):
            return self.frames[page_name]


    class Page1(tk.Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            self.controller = controller

            name = tk.StringVar()
            dob = tk.StringVar()
            cardnumber = tk.StringVar()
            email = tk.StringVar()

            self.fullname = tk.Entry(self, width=15, textvariable=name)
            self.fullname.pack()

            self.dob = tk.Entry(self, width=15, textvariable=dob)
            self.dob.pack()

            self.cardnumber = tk.Entry(self, width=15, textvariable=cardnumber)
            self.cardnumber.pack()

            self.email = tk.Entry(self, width=15, textvariable=email)
            self.email.pack()

            self.msglabel = tk.Label(self, text="")
            self.msglabel.pack()

            def accept():
                try:
                    if name.get() == "" or dob.get() == "" or cardnumber.get() == "" or email.get() == "":
                        raise ValueError
                    else:
                        self.msglabel.config(text="Done.")
             # Instead of using many if statements, is there a better solution to handling any errors? Or another way aside from try/except?   
                except ValueError:
                    self.msglabel.config(text="Entry error")

            self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Cmd", command=accept)
            self.button.pack()


    class Page2(tk.Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


    app = Main()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> Instead of using many if statements, is there a better solution to
>   handling any errors?

Don't you mean:

> Instead of using one if-statement with a long, complex conditional
>   expression, is there a better solution to handling any errors?

If I'm understanding you correctly, and unless I'm missing something critical, you can "unroll" the if-statement in your try-catch block by using `assert`:

```
try:
    assert name.get() != ""
    assert dob.get() != ""
    assert cardnumber.get() != ""
    assert email.get() != ""
except AssertionError:
    self.msglabel.config(text="Entry error")
else:
    self.msglabel.config(text="Done.")
```

Which, thanks to truthyness of non-empty strings, can be further reduced to:

```
try:
    assert name.get()
    assert dob.get()
    assert cardnumber.get()
    assert email.get()
except AssertionError:
    self.msglabel.config(text="Entry error")
else:
    self.msglabel.config(text="Done.")
```

Which you can maybe make cuter by doing:

```
try:
    query_items = [name, dob, cardnumber, email]
    for item in query_items:
        assert item.get()
except AssertionError:
    self.msglabel.config(text="Entry error")
else:
    self.msglabel.config(text="Done.")
```

**EDIT** - Just for fun, here are some alternatives without exceptions:

```
query_items = [name, dob, cardnumber, email]
if all(item.get() for item in query_items):
    self.msglabel.config(text="Done.")
else:
    self.msglabel.config(text="Entry error")
```

Or, the inverse (yay DeMorgan's Law):

```
query_items = [name, dob, cardnumber, email]
if any(not item.get() for item in query_items):
    self.msglabel.config(text="Entry error")
else:
    self.msglabel.config(text="Done.")
```

Or the cute (not necessarily readable) version:

```
query_items = [name, dob, cardnumber, email]
label_text = ["Entry error", "Done."][all(item.get() for item in query_items)]
self.msglabel.config(text=label_text)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was getting at. I didn't know about this at all!

Comment: Glad it's helpful. Check out the edit I made to my original post if you're curious about alternatives without exceptions.